# Is the PayPal live client id through the API to pass is secure?

Tags: paypal

I have the PayPal development in my project.

In the frontend, I use:

```
    // data
    ...
    credentials: {
      sandbox: this.PAYPAL_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID,
      production: this.PAYMENT.PAYPAL_LIVE_CLIENT_ID,
    },
    ...
    // template to use
       <PayPal :amount="amount"
              currency="USD"
              :client="credentials"  // there is the data.
              env="sandbox"

              :items="pay_items"
              >
```

Because the `this.PAYMENT.PAYPAL_LIVE_CLIENT_ID` is dynamic, some time it maybe changed.

so I want to through the API to pass the `PAYPAL_LIVE_CLIENT_ID` from backend to frontend, because I don't know whether the `PAYPAL_LIVE_CLIENT_ID` is secure if is transparent for everyone.

somebody can tell me about the live client id?
[there](https://developer.paypal.com/search/?q=live+client++id) maybe find some useful information.